# How do I install Bloomberg API blpapi

Tags: bloomberg

Hi I am trying to pip install Bloomberg API blpapi in anaconda prompt...so i tried...

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda install -c conda-forge blpapi
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

then as per the bbg api website  i tried...

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
Looking in indexes: https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple
Looking in links: https://nexus-devops.income.com.sg/repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blpapi
```

finally i tried...

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
Looking in indexes: https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple
Looking in links: https://nexus-devops.income.com.sg/repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))': /pip/simple/blpapi/
Could not fetch URL https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple/blpapi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bcms.bloomberg.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pip/simple/blpapi/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)'))) - skipping
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027AF2844220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027AF2844430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027AF2844640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027AF2844850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /repository/pypi-all
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027AF2844A60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /repository/pypi-all
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blpapi
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blpapi
```

It shouldn't be due to the environment as i can download other packages like xbbg using pip install with no problem